# Django TypeError Field 'id' expected a number but got SimpleLazyObject

Tags: python, django, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to make my openai chatbot save chats for the user that is making them, but it is giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2053, in get_prep_value       
    return int(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'SimpleLazyObject'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\Downloads\finalproject\finalproject\django_chatbot\chatbot\views.py", line 29, in chatbot
    chats = Chat.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1436, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1454, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1461, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace     
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1534, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1565, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1480, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1307, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 166, in get_prep_lookup    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nathan A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2055, in get_prep_value       
    raise e.__class__(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x0000025FE3733310>>.
```

Here's my code:

```
def chatbot(request):
    chats = Chat.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        response = ask_openai(message)

        chat = Chat(user=request.user, message=message, response=response, created_at=timezone.now())
        chat.save()
        return JsonResponse({'message': message, 'response': response})
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'chats': chats})
```

I don't know what's going on I'm new to `chatgpt openai api`. If you need more code I can provide some more. It says that `chats = Chat.objects.filter(user=request.user)` is the problem.

Comment: how did u define `Chat` in chatbot()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need to make sure that the user is authenticated before attempting to filter on the user field in your view if a user is None you will get None and cant interpret with  object

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def chatbot(request):
    chats = Chat.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        response = ask_openai(message)

        chat = Chat(user=request.user, message=message, response=response, created_at=timezone.now())
        chat.save()
        return JsonResponse({'message': message, 'response': response})

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'chats': chats})
```

Comment: This fixes the problem except that it now says page not found. it is now bringing me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/ instead of 127.0.0.1:8000/login. How can I fix this?

Comment: that is different question regarding login redirect you need to ask another question regarding  login rederiect as of now above solution is for the question you asked